# Deleting sublists where an element repeats beyond a repetition threshold

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, pattern-matching

I am looking for some help constructing a function `Part[M_,N_]` which outputs the list of all integer partitions of positive integers up to $M$ such that in each partition, no number is repeated more than $N+1$ times.  For example, when $N=3$, the partition `{1,4,5,5,5,5,5,7}` of $37$ should not count, because there are more than four (i.e., $N+1$) copies of $5$.

I'd appreciate any assistance here!

Comment: Is it necessary to use `DeleteCases`?

Comment: I suppose not.  From my very limited knowledge, it was just the main approach I could think of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]

f[m_, n_] := Select[LessEqualThan[1 + n] @* Max @* Counts] @*
    Map[Apply[Sequence] @* IntegerPartitions] @* Range @ m;
```

***Examples:***

```
f[5, 2]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2}, {1, 1}, {3}, {2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {4}, {3, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {5},
>  {4, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1}}
> ```

```
f[9, 2]
```

[image]

```
Length @ f[37, 3]
```

> ```
> 62483
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[1];
n = 2;
plist = RandomSample[IntegerPartitions[37, {6, 7}], 200];
```

The list is still too large; let's reduce it to 20 entries for better visualization.

```
xlist = plist[[1 ;; 20]]
```

[image]

- For n=2, four repetitions of an element are not allowed. The entries underlined in red should be deleted.
- For n=3, five repetitions of an element are not allowed. The entries enclosed by the green box should be deleted.

---

```
pos = First /@ 
  Position[Tally /@ xlist, {_, x_ /; x > n + 1}, Infinity, 
   Heads -> False]
```

> {1, 6, 13, 16, 17, 19}

```
Delete[xlist, List /@ pos]
```

> ```
> {{23, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {21, 5, 4, 4, 2, 1}, {15, 11, 5, 4, 1, 1}, {12, 
>   7, 6, 4, 4, 2, 2}, {10, 9, 9, 7, 1, 1}, {14, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3}, {13,
>    11, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1}, {14, 10, 4, 4, 4, 1}, {17, 6, 4, 4, 3, 2, 
>   1}, {16, 5, 5, 5, 4, 1, 1}, {9, 9, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2}, {14, 12, 3, 3, 2,
>    2, 1}, {21, 9, 2, 2, 2, 1}, {12, 10, 9, 2, 2, 2}}
> ```

Now you can turn it into a function with `n` as a parameter if you wish to. `IntegerPartitions` grow in size rapidly so an attempt to make tuples of two large sets may run into difficulties. I hope this gives you a pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

```
part[m_, n_] := DeleteCases[
  IntegerPartitions[m], _?(Max[Tally[#][[All, 2]]] > n &)]

part[37, 2]
```

> {{37}, {36, 1}, {35, 2}, {35, 1, 1}, {34, 3}, {34, 2, 1}, ... }